# webView JavaFX Redirect A Certain URL When Accessed

Tags: java, javafx, webview, webengine

I am using javaFX webView how can I redirect a certain URL to other.

example :-

```
if user access 
example.com/pathabc
redirect it to
example.com/pathxyz
```

Thank You.

Edit :-

Let's say if I loaded example.com (I can't change this I have to load example.com)

The page example.com has a link to example.com/pathabc and when the user clicks on it can be accessed.

But I don't want to user to access example.com/pathabc so I want to redirect it example.com/pathxyz

Please tell me how can I redirect it.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. With a web view you have to explicitly call `load(...)` to load a URL anyway. So just don't load a URL you don't want to load.

Comment: @James_D I have updated the question I hope it can be understood properly now.  thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a listener to the [`locationProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#locationProperty), and redirect it if the new location matches a URL you want to redirect.

e.g.

```
webEngine.locationProperty().addListener((obs, oldLocation, newLocation) -> {
    if (newLocation != null && newLocation.endsWith("example.com/pathabc")) {
        webEngine.load("http://example.com/pathxyz");
    }
});
```

You will probably need to refine the criterion for a matching URL, etc, but this should give you the basic idea.